# Running JBoss-5.1.0.GA as a service / daemon on Red Hat?

Tags: linux, jboss, daemon

I am using JBoss 5.1.0 GA on Red Hat (Amazon ECS)...

Am trying to set it up so JBoss will run as a service / daemon (right now it only starts up when I manually SSH and invoke sh $JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh).

Here's what I did so far:

(1) Created the following jboss script in /etc/init.d/:

```
JBOSS_HOME=${JBOSS_HOME:-"/usr/jboss-5.1.0.GA"}

JBOSS_USER=${JBOSS_USER:-"jboss"}

JAVAPTH=${JAVAPTH:-"/usr/java/jdk/bin"}

JBOSS_CONF=${JBOSS_CONF:-"default"}

JBOSS_BIND_ADDR=${JBOSS_HOST:+"-b $JBOSS_HOST"}

JBOSSCP=${JBOSSCP:-"$JBOSS_HOME/bin/shutdown.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/client/jnet.jar"}

JBOSSSH=${JBOSSSH:-"$JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -c $JBOSS_CONF $JBOSS_BIND_ADDR"}

if [ "$JBOSS_USER" = "RUNASIS" ]; then
  SUBIT=""
else
  SUBIT="su - $JBOSS_USER -c "
fi

if [ -n "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" -a ! -d "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" ]; then
  # ensure the file exists
  touch $JBOSS_CONSOLE
  if [ ! -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
    chown $JBOSS_USER $JBOSS_CONSOLE
  fi 
fi

if [ -n "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" -a ! -f "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" ]; then
  echo "WARNING: location for saving console log invalid: $JBOSS_CONSOLE"
  echo "WARNING: ignoring it and using /dev/null"
  JBOSS_CONSOLE="/dev/null"
fi

JBOSS_CONSOLE=${JBOSS_CONSOLE:-"/dev/null"}

JBOSS_CMD_START="cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin; $JBOSSSH"
JBOSS_CMD_STOP=${JBOSS_CMD_STOP:-"java -classpath $JBOSSCP org.jboss.Shutdown --shutdown"}

if [ -z "`echo $PATH | grep $JAVAPTH`" ]; then
  export PATH=$PATH:$JAVAPTH
fi

if [ ! -d "$JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
  echo JBOSS_HOME does not exist as a valid directory : $JBOSS_HOME
  exit 1
fi

echo JBOSS_CMD_START = $JBOSS_CMD_START

case "$1" in
start)
    cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin
    if [ -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
        eval $JBOSS_CMD_START >${JBOSS_CONSOLE} 2>&1 &
    else
        $SUBIT "$JBOSS_CMD_START >${JBOSS_CONSOLE} 2>&1 &" 
    fi
    ;;
stop)
    if [ -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
        $JBOSS_CMD_STOP
    else
        $SUBIT "$JBOSS_CMD_STOP"
    fi 
    ;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
*)
    echo "usage: $0 (start|stop|restart|help)"
esac
```

(2) Made script executable and changed ownership by doing the following:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/jboss
sudo chmod ug+x /etc/init.d/jboss
```

(3) When I tried to start it, I received the following output (and JBoss didn't start):

```
JBOSS_CMD_START = cd /usr/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin; /usr/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/run.sh -c default
```

Questions:

(1) What am I possibly doing wrong?

(2) How do I set it up so it runs as root user? Do I have to add a JBoss group and a JBoss user?

I can manually run JBoss through $JBOSS_HOME/bin but would love to have it running all the time...

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: socal, this is your second post here. Server administration related questions belong on serverfault. stackoverflow is for programming questions only

Answer (score 2):

Any particular reason that you have an aversion to using the bin/jboss_init_redhat.sh SysV init script that comes already with the JBoss 5.1.0.GA release? I use it on several RHEL and CentOS systems and have absolutely no problem with JBoss starting up on reboot.

I only had to do a minor change to get it to handle `chkconfig` without any problems. This change consisted of the following near the top of the script:

```
--- bin/jboss_init_redhat.sh    2009-05-22 11:01:22.000000000 -0400
+++ /etc/rc.d/init.d/jboss  2009-06-07 22:05:17.000000000 -0400
@@ -4,6 +4,10 @@
 #
 # JBoss Control Script
 #
+# chkconfig: - 85 15
+# description: JBoss Application Server
+# processname: jboss
+
 # To use this script run it as root - it will switch to the specified user
 #
 # Here is a little (and extremely primitive) startup/shutdown script
```

I then simply copied it to /etc/rc.d/init.d as `jboss` and ran `chkconfig --add jboss`. You can verify it's active with `chkconfig --list jboss` and see that it's set to **on** for the runlevels you want, usually 2-5 which it activates .

Answer (score 1):

The provided init script is pretty terrible, and not very reliable.

I've created an alternative init script that should be more robust: https://jira.jboss.org/jira/browse/JBPAPP-3194

All feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, Red Hat's JBoss 5.1 **EAP** distribution is missing **bin/jboss_init_redhat.sh**, although the HPUX and Solaris versions are there, which is a bit confusing for a Red Hat distribution

I thoroughly documented the procedures for setting the daemon up here...
http://www.forwardslashbin.com/?p=108

Answer (score 0):

Remove the eval from the start line. Also, set JBOSS_CONSOLE so it doesn't redirect all errors to /dev/null.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a jboss user for it to run properly. According to the script as given above, it would be named "jboss"(without quotes).

```
[root@destination-host ~]# /usr/sbin/useradd jboss
```

The only way to get the script to run as the root user is to be the root user when starting it, or via sudo. I would strongly advise against running JBoss per se as root.

Answer (score 0):

In doing and working around same requirement I have come to following very brief changes

#!/bin/sh

# chkconfig: 345 90 10 
 # description: Runs the JBoss Application Server 5
 # processname: jboss
 # pidfile: /var/run/jboss_m2i.pid

1 - The above points are made are made for chkconfig utility for service.

# $Id: jboss_init_redhat.sh 81068 2008-11-14 15:14:35Z dimitris@jboss.org $
 # JBoss Control Script
 # To use this script run it as root - it will switch to the specified user
 # Here is a little (and extremely primitive) startup/shutdown script
 # for RedHat systems. It assumes that JBoss lives in /usr/local/jboss,
 # it's run by user 'jboss' and JDK binaries are in /usr/local/jdk/bin.
 # All this can be changed in the script itself. 
 #
 # Either modify this script for your requirements or just ensure that
 # the following variables are set correctly before calling the script.

#define where jboss is - this is the directory containing directories log, bin, conf etc
 2 - Here you have to give your jboss server home location.
 JBOSS_HOME=${JBOSS_HOME:-"/home/jboss_user/servers/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA"}

3- point three of modification

#define the user under which jboss will run, or use 'RUNASIS' to run as the current user 
JBOSS_USER=${JBOSS_USER:-"jboss_user"}

#make sure java is in your path
 JAVAPTH=${JAVAPTH:-"/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin"}

4 - Point 4 where server profile is specified
 #configuration to use, usually one of 'minimal', 'default', 'all' , 'test'
 JBOSS_CONF=${JBOSS_CONF:-"test"}

5 - point 5 where binding address is specified. This point is very important if you assign it 0.0.0.0 the rmi / jndi exception will be raised.

#if JBOSS_HOST specified, use -b to bind jboss services to that address
 JBOSS_BIND_ADDR=${JBOSS_HOST:-"10.168.1.10"}

6 - Point 6 variables which should be defined to shutdown the server.
   here 1299 depends on your port off-set change into your binding configuration 
   $JBOSS_HOME/server/server_def_profile/conf/bindingservice.beans/META-INF/bindings-jboss-beans.xml
  6.0 this can be checked by  -- netstat command

# porta do JNDI service do JBoss (usada para shutdown)
   JBOSS_JNP_PORT=${JBOSS_JNP_PORT:-"1299"}
  JBOSS_ADMIN_USER=${JMX_USER:-"admin"}
  JBOSS_ADMIN_PWD=${JMX_PWD:-"admin"}

#define the classpath for the shutdown class
 JBOSSCP=${JBOSSCP:-"$JBOSS_HOME/bin/shutdown.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/client/jnet.jar"}

7 . Point 7 of modification. in running script. This different from standard distribution.

#define the script to use to start jboss
 JBOSSSH=${JBOSSSH:-"$JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.sh -c $JBOSS_CONF -b $JBOSS_BIND_ADDR"}

if [ "$JBOSS_USER" = "RUNASIS" ]; then
   SUBIT=""
 else
   SUBIT="su - $JBOSS_USER -c "
 fi

if [ -n "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" -a ! -d "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" ]; then
  # ensure the file exists
  touch $JBOSS_CONSOLE
  if [ ! -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
    chown $JBOSS_USER $JBOSS_CONSOLE
  fi
fi

if [ -n "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" -a ! -f "$JBOSS_CONSOLE" ]; then
  echo "WARNING: location for saving console log invalid: $JBOSS_CONSOLE"
  echo "WARNING: ignoring it and using /dev/null"
  JBOSS_CONSOLE="/dev/null"
fi

#define what will be done with the console log
JBOSS_CONSOLE=${JBOSS_CONSOLE:-"/dev/null"}

JBOSS_CMD_START="cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin; $JBOSSSH"

8 - Point 8 , one of the major modification to shutdown the server using service command.

JBOSS_CMD_STOP=${JBOSS_CMD_STOP:-"java -classpath $JBOSSCP org.jboss.Shutdown --shutdown \
                                -s jnp://$JBOSS_BIND_ADDR:$JBOSS_JNP_PORT \
                                -u $JBOSS_ADMIN_USER -p $JBOSS_ADMIN_PWD"}
if [ -z "`echo $PATH | grep $JAVAPTH`" ]; then
  export PATH=$PATH:$JAVAPTH
fi

if [ ! -d "$JBOSS_HOME" ]; then
  echo JBOSS_HOME does not exist as a valid directory : $JBOSS_HOME
  exit 1
fi

echo JBOSS_CMD_START = $JBOSS_CMD_START

case "$1" in
start)
    cd $JBOSS_HOME/bin
    if [ -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
        eval $JBOSS_CMD_START >${JBOSS_CONSOLE} 2>&1 &
    else
        $SUBIT "$JBOSS_CMD_START >${JBOSS_CONSOLE} 2>&1 &"
    fi
    ;;
stop)
    if [ -z "$SUBIT" ]; then
        $JBOSS_CMD_STOP
    else
        $SUBIT "$JBOSS_CMD_STOP"
    fi
    ;;
restart)
    $0 stop
    $0 start
    ;;
*)
    echo "usage: $0 (start|stop|restart|help)"
esac

### Use following command to add this script to chkconfig service and test

chkconfig --add jboss  - to add

chkconfig --list jboss - to list

## Use following command to run  and stop the services.

service jboss start

service jboss stop